# How to stop game but animation is running?

Tags: unity, animation

i want stop my game but the animation is runnig.
how to make it ??
for Example :
i call anim,
i want when press the eScape , my game stop but animation is running.

```
void Update()
{
   myAnim.setSpeed(animSpeed);
   myAnim.run();

   if(Input.getKey(keyCode.Escape)
   {
      Time.timeScale=0;
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `Time.timeScale = 0` to stop everything.

Comment: i want Stop the game , but want my animation is playing .... @vadim

Comment: You could disable all the components that make things move and play the animation

Answer (score 1):

In your Animator Component, change Update Mode to *Unscaled Time*.

Now the Animator can play even when TimeScale is 0. Useful for pause menus and similar.

[Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html)